# Cosine of matrix and matrix of cosines

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have cosine of the matrix
$$
\tag 1 \cos\left( \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\right)
$$
May I write it in a form
$$
\tag 2 \begin{pmatrix} \cos(a) & \cos(b) \\ \cos(c) & \cos(d)\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard definition of cosine of a matrix, sometimes useful in thinking about differential equations, is
$$
\cos A = I - \frac 1 2 A^2 + \frac 1 {24} A^4 - \frac 1 {720} A^6 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n} {(2n)!} A^{2n}.
$$
This is the same series that is the power expansion of $\cos A$ when $A$ is a real or complex number.

Comment: So You state that the matrix $(1)$ in my question isn't equal to $(2)$?

Comment: They're not equal because matrix multiplication is not term by term.  Do you know how to multiply matrices?  Note in particular that $$\cos\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] \ne \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos0 & \cos0 \\ \cos0 & \cos0 \end{array}\right].$$